# How to register Exec callbacks in gorm?

Tags: go, grails-orm, go-gorm

I want to globally capture the case of db write failure, and then do something.

Now I capture the results of create, update, and delete by registering callbacks.but I found that in addition to these three write methods, there is also Exec. , now I don't know how to capture the result of the operation performed through Exec.